# GNU Parallel: Event not found (!~)

Tags: shell, quoting

**About my code:**

1. get all .txt files
2. for each file, execute the awk command. All files
   are processed in parallel
3. if colum 3 does NOT contain "needle",
   write line to file

**Result:**

-bash: !~: event not found

**Code:**

```
ls *.txt | parallel "awk -F '\t' -v OFS='\t' '$1 { if($3 !~ /needle/){print;} ;}' {} > {}.output"
```

**Question:**

- What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a quoting issue. Perhaps the easiest way to debug this is to pass the option `--dry-run` to parallel:

```
$ parallel --dry-run "awk -F '\t' -v OFS='\t' '$1 { if($3 !~ /needle/){print;} ;}' {} > {}.output" ::: in
awk -F '\t' -v OFS='\t' ' { if( ~ /needle/){print;} ;}' in > in.output
```

There you can see that your variables `$1` and `$3` have disappeared, and that `!~` has been expanded to `~` (in my case). All those have special meaning for the bash shell, and should be protected if they are meant for awk instead. Try the following instead (I also altered the awk script to fit your description):

```
parallel awk -F '\\t' -vOFS='\t' $'\'($3 !~ /needle/) { print }\'' \>{}.output {} ::: *.txt
```

The reason why those expansions happened is that the tokens were inside double quotes (they are within single quotes within double quotes, but the shell only concerns itself with the outer quotes).

Note that I also [avoid parsing the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 0):

When quoting gets too tough consider using bash functions:

```
myfunc() {
  awk -F '\t' -v OFS='\t' '$1 { if($3 !~ /needle/){print;} ;}' "$1" > "$1".output
}
export -f myfunc

parallel myfunc {} ::: *.txt
```